# Java - Doing something when button clicked, then revert it

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Ok, so I'm doing a Java window (a JFrame, doesn't really matter what it is for) and I have a button on it. What I want to approach is when the button is clicked, it changes its text, then the app does something, and when it's finished the button gets its initial text back.
Something like this...

```
JButton myButton = new JButton("Initial");
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ((JButton) e.getSource()).setText("New");
        //Do other things
        //Do more other things
        ((JButton) e.getSource()).setText("Initial");
    }
});
```

That's what I've tried so far, but I know it doesn't work as expected (all the code executes. I'm not really an expert and I'm doing this things to learn, so I have no clue if there's a way to do it or not.

I've already looked for a solution to this in the web but I've not found anything (maybe I didn't search properly), so I hope there's someone who can help me with this!

PS: Sorry if my English is not perfect, I know about it. Ask me if something isn't clear about the question. Thanks to all!

Kevin.

EDIT: The app is a sudoku solver, so it takes a while *//doing other things*. Thats why I'm trying to change the *solve* button text (so it sais it *is solving* and when it finished it says *solved*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is not wrong!  Take a look at my example below:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    public MainFrame() {
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

        JButton myButton = new JButton("Initial");
        add(myButton);

        myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                final JButton triggerBtn = (JButton) e.getSource();
                final String originalValue = triggerBtn.getText();
                triggerBtn.setText("New");

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Speak softly and carry a big stick and you will go far.");

                triggerBtn.setText(originalValue);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
                mainFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you run this you will see that the button is changed.  If you were to change the `showMessageDialog` line to `Thread.sleep(10*1000)`, you would *not* see a change!  This is because you're running the event on the dispatcher thread and the text, even though it is changed, will not allow the change event to be triggered until your method finishes.

Consider the following alternative if the work you're doing is on the same thread:

```
    myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
            final JButton triggerBtn = (JButton) e.getSource();
            final String originalValue = triggerBtn.getText();
            triggerBtn.setText("New");

            SwingWorker<Void, Void> sw = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    Thread.sleep(10*1000);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    triggerBtn.setText(originalValue);
                }

            };
            sw.execute();
        }
    });
```

This sets the text, and launches a `SwingWorker` to run the job asynchronously.  Once finished, the dispatcher thread will update the text without requiring the dispatcher thread to be tied up waiting for it to finish (and so events are therefore handled properly).

Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: Man, this just works perfect.
I really apreciate your help. Thanks for using your time with me!

Comment: Must say I used the second method you mentioned as I was doing things in the same thread.

Comment: @KevinRomero I figured as much.  Remember that it is an event that causes update of the text after you change it.  If you occupy the dispatcher thread, it will never get around to updating it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
JButton myButton = new JButton("Initial");
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        myButton.setText("New");
        //Do other things
        //Do more other things
        myButton.setText("Initial");
    }
});
```

In your example you're missing `actionPerformed` and you're not accessing button directly (I can't say what's `e` in your example)

Comment: That's cool and all, but it's unlikely to solve the question, as the text of the button won't be changed

Comment: It was a typo missing. I've tried it. Thanks anyway, I've added it.
And I have tried accesing the button directly too and it does the same (nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Just save your current text in a local variable and set it back after you've performed your other actions.
You should also make sure it's really the button that you clicked or at least check instanceof JButton before casting.

```
final JButton myButton = new JButton("Initial");
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == myButton) {
            String initialText = myButton.getText();
            myButton.setText("New");
            // Do other things
            // Do more other things
            myButton.setText(initialText);
        }
    }
});
```

You were also missing out on your actionPerformed method, the code in the question won't compile - I guess you just wrote it in the editor.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to write actionPerformed method (I already writed it).
About your answer, I tried it, but still doen's do the thing. I made an edit to be more clear.

Comment: Does your text change when you use myButton.setText("some text") right after declaring it? If so there's some problem with your ActionListener.